# Flash sound actionscript start Music and stop automatically background sound

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am working on flash. I want to stop background sound automatically when I click on MUSIC ON button and start(background sound automatically) when i click on MUSIC OFF.

Please give me solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

music_on_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickStart);
music_off_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickStop);


function onClickStart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
mySound.load(new URLRequest("myFavSong.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();
}

function onClickStop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
myChannel.stop();
}
```

For more queries you can also go through these links,
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;
mySound.load(new URLRequest("mysong.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();

pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPause);

function onClickPause(e:MouseEvent):void{
lastPosition = myChannel.position;
myChannel.stop();
}

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlay);

function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void{
myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
}
```